# How to round up in java?

Tags: java, decimal, rounding

im trying to display a float number in 5 digits rounding up in the last digit, for example : 0.123455 will be displayed as 0.12346, and 0.123454 will be 0.12345. 
My current code (not properly working) is as follows:

```
int iFactorSum = 100000;
            int iRoundSum = (int) (fSumatoria * iFactorSum + 0.5);
            fSumatoria = (float) iRoundSum / iFactorSum;
```

fSumatoria storages the number i want to convert. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To round up, you can use `Math.ceil(numberGrade)`.

To round to the nearest integer, use `Math.round(numberGrade)`.

See: [the Math class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705728/8112776).

Answer (score -3):

Use `Math.round()` to round up floating point numbers

see 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)

Comment: That’s just wrong. Look at the duplicate and the other answer

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt he wanted to round up in fifth position after the point, so he multiplied 100000 for it and then rounding it.

Comment: I’ll grant you that the ops title and body of the question are entirely different. But your code doesn’t do what the op requested either, does it?